The question regarding pointers qualified with "restrict" in C
C11  6.7.3.1:

1 Let D be a declaration of an ordinary identifier that provides a
means of designating an
object P as a restrict-qualified pointer to type T.
2 If D appears inside a block and does not have storage class extern, let B denote the
block. If D appears in the list of parameter declarations of a function definition, let B
denote the associated block. Otherwise, let B denote the block of main (or the block of
whatever function is called at program startup in a freestanding environment).
3 In what follows, a pointer expression E is said to be based on object P if (at some
sequence point in the execution of B prior to the evaluation of E) modifying P to point to
a copy of the array object into which it formerly pointed would change the value of E.137)
Note that ‘‘based’’ is defined only for expressions with pointer types.
4 During each execution of B, let L be any lvalue that has &L based on P. If L is used to
access the value of the object X that it designates, and X is also modified (by any means),
then the following requirements apply: T shall not be const-qualified. Every other lvalue
used to access the value of X shall also have its address based on P. Every access that
modifies X shall be considered also to modify P, for the purposes of this subclause...
137) In other words, E depends on the value of P itself rather than on the value of an object referenced indirectly through P. For example, if identifier p has type (int **restrict), then the pointer expressions p and p+1 are based on the restricted pointer object designated by p, but the pointer expressions *p and p[1] are not.

Based on this sentence, I conceived a piece of code:
int main() 
{    
    int  A = 5;   
    int* restrict P;
    P = &A;           
    *P = 10;
    int *N = P; 
    *N = 20;
}

My doubt comes from the sentence "Every access that modifies X shall be considered also to modify P, for the purposes of this subclause."
First of all, I think this piece of code is strictly in line with the standard and there is no undefined behavior.
Secondly, *N belongs to "Every access that modifies X",What does this have to do with modifying P?P is a pointer object, and X is the object it points to. Does modifying the object pointed to by the pointer also count as modifying the pointer?
The above is my question.
Thank you for your reading.

I think the sentence before the one you highlighted covers your code: Every other lvalue used to access the value of X shall also have its address based on P.

If you do things that wouldn’t be undefined behaviour without “restrict” but would be with “restrict” then you have undefined behaviour. That’s all that restrict does: Make certain code undefined behaviour. Thats the whole point of it.

In this case you have no undefined behaviour because N is based on P. If you wrote N = &A then N wouldn’t be based on P leading to undefined behaviour.

I wonder if this statement that modifying X is considered to modify P is in case there is a restricted pointer Q pointed to the restricted pointer P, which points to X. Then it is saying, if X is modified, the conditions also apply to P, meaning every access to P has to be through an lvalue based on Q. Is that needed?

@Jonathan Leffler:Yes. Then what does the highlighted part mean? Don't you think this sentence is very strange?

@gnasher729:Then, what does the highlighted part mean? I have difficulty understanding this sentence.

@Eric Postpischil:My point is that, literally understood, this sentence can also be said like this: "Modifying the object pointed to by a pointer is also regarded as modifying the pointer."But how could this be possible? So I think this sentence is very strange. Maybe I misunderstood something somewhere.

This very part of the standard has been discussed multiple times before on SO. I think the consensus is that it's not well-written and is to be ignored - someone in the ISO C WG had too much free time.

@Eric Postpischil:Oh! I think I understand what you mean! The answer to this question is here:https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_294.htm
